# c# application with on-screen keyboard

Tags: c#

I'm making a Windows form application in c# and im creating on-screen keyboard for this application and i have some problems with that, because I don't know how to do few things.

**What i have**

> - Form1 with few textboxes and few richtextboxes.
> - panel1 with richtextbox and 5 buttons (A, B, C, DEL, ENTER).

**What I want?**

> - Everytime I click on any textbox or any richtextbox I want panel1 to show up.
> - I want the text from the textbox i have clicked to be displayed in a richtextbox on panel1.
> - When I click "ENTER" button on panel1 I want the text from richtextbox on panel1 to be transferred to textbox i have clicked before. (and ofcourse panel1 would hide after that).

I already made panel1 to show up when I click on textbox or richtextbox (I've used "Enter" event) and panel1 will hide when I click "ENTER" button on it. Is there maybe any other way to show panel1 everytime I click on textbox or richtextbox without coding "Enter" event for each one?

Now the hardest part is transferring text from form to panel and vice versa. To transfer text from the clicked textbox I've simply added a line of code to "Enter" event:

> > textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text;

Transferring text from richtextbox1 back to textbox is my main problem... I have solution for that but im looking for a correct and simple one... my solution is too noobish and complicated...

**Will explain here what im looking for:**
For example if int can remember number and string can remember text. I want something which can remember which textbox i've last clicked. I hope u can understand what I mean.

My english is not my main language so please reply if u cant understand anything and i will try my best to explain.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is a general way to do textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text, (without hardcoding), right?

Answer (score 0):

I would do these:

1. Create a base user control that derives from Textbox (if you'll be using only textboxes) or from a Control if there will be more than the textboxes used.
2. Handle the "Enter" event just as you do now in that base class.
3. Create the class that will derive from the EventArgs class and that will store a value of yout control. Let's call it "TextboxArgs" for now.
4. In the base user control, create an event and raise it in the "Enter" handler that you have and use a "TextboxArgs" class form step 3 to pass the text as the event argument.
5. Subscribe to this event in your panel so it will react properly.

Now, just use this base user control that you have for each textbox and it will raise an event and pass it's value as an argument. Panel will respond to it. If you do it that way then you won't need any additional coding no matter how many textboxes you add.

Comment: "base user control" can you show me an example? or can you do this in a simple test project and show me? beacuse i have never used base user control before... and honestly im completly lost.